# Postgres tablespace detecting if linux or windows

Tags: postgresql

- We have custom init script which work for windows.
- They create the dev-database and set up some test users.
- Some devs are working on linux based installation, but they touch the scripts every time setting up a database.

Is it possible to detect within postgresql if running on windows or linux? Or is it possible to do a fallback for the tablespace creation?
Currently its working for windows:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE foo_bar LOCATION 'C:\foo_bar_tablespace';
```

I to use somthing like:

```
IF onWindows THEN
    CREATE TABLESPACE foo_bar LOCATION 'C:\foo_bar_tablespace';
ELSE
    CREATE TABLESPACE foo_bar LOCATION '/var/lib/postgresql/data/foo_bar_tablespace';
END IF;
```

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do that inside of a plain SQL script (because you can not put `create tablespace` into a function or a DO block)

Comment: How exactly are you running those scripts? If that is through a batch file or shell script (that runs `psql`), then you could make the distinction inside those.

Comment: the script is run via the intellij function (for now) 'Run SQL Script...'

Comment: Maybe using [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org/)  to manage your schema migrations might be an option. That allows conditional execution based on operating system (or database product or other things like environment)

Comment: It won't work always, but if the parameter `lc_collate` usually looks different on Windows and UNIX.

Comment: It should be easy with a scripting language (perl, python, ruby...). You can recognize the o.s. from `version()`

Comment: well, show SHOW server_version resturns 10.5 (Debian 10.5-... how can i convert it to an expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a superuser, a safe way to tell if you are on Windows, where path names start with an upper case letter, followed by `:\', would be:

```
SELECT current_setting('data_directory') SIMILAR TO '[A-Z]:\\%' AS is_windows;
```